# Concatenate Server Side Code in Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$("#Selection").change(function () {
    var text = $("#Selection option:selected").text();
    alert(text);
    var valueSelected= this.value;
    alert(valueOfLanguage);
    var url = 'OpenServerQuote Html.SelectorLink("' + valueSelected+ '", "[' + text + ']", "' + text + '", null) CloseServerQuote';

    var hrefValue = $(url).attr("href");
    alert(hrefValue);
});
```

I need to pass the value and text of dropdown to a HTML helper method and get the the result.
But when I pass the value to html helper as shown above, instead of values valueselected string is passed.
Any pointers how to proceed on this.

```
*OpenServerQuote = <%
CloseServerQuote = %>
```

Comment: Add four spaces to the beginning of each line you want to display as code. It will make your code more easily readable. ==> http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: with a line like `valueSelected= this.value`, what is the difference between `value` and `valueselected`? Also, what are you trying to do? How can you create server-side code using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

One of us is mighty confused here... You are trying to execute server side code with client side parameter? It does not work that way...
You either need to execute Ajax request with the parameter and then run the code on the server side or have server side code output a template string and then substitute your `valueSelected` client-side.